# Regexp PayPal Transaction ID from text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I run a website that accepts PayPal payments. When users have questions regarding their purchase they will send me their transaction ID through a self-coded ticket system.

I would like to turn the transactions IDs into URLs (to a link that will pull up transaction info) to make everything faster for me.

I know transaction IDs are 17 characters long. How would I go about this?

**UPDATE:**

When users post let us say. "Hi there, my name is John Doe. I made a purchase and I'm having issues with it. Transaction ID: XXXXXX". I need to be able to turn the XXXX into a link that pulls up transaction info. I can't figure out how to create this in PHP with preg_replace, so it only formats the transaction ID into the link.

I have the link that is needed to lookup the transaction info, but I just do not know how to use regex to find the transaction ID and then wrap a link around it.

Comment: what have you tried? the length of transaction is irrelevant..

Comment: You are not trying to put together a phishing system, right? Somehow I find it a bit suspicious for someone to be able to code a ticket system but unable to put together a link. But that is just me.

Comment: @RST When users post let us say. "Hi there, my name is John Doe. I made a purchase and I'm having issues with it. Transaction ID: XXXXXX". I need to be able to turn the XXXX into a link that pulls up transaction info. I can't figure out how to create this in PHP with preg_replace, so it only formats the transaction ID into the link.

Comment: I have the link that is needed to lookup the transaction info, but I just do not know how to use regex to find the transaction ID and then wrap a link around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might go for:

```
\b[\dA-Z]{17}\b
```

Which looks for a character string of length 17 with borders on both sides. If you know, it has only digits, this might be as well `~\b\d{17}\b~` but you did not elaborate on the specifications, really.

---

In `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
When users post let us say. "Hi there, my name is John Doe. I made a purchase and I'm having issues with it. Transaction ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX". I need to be able to turn the XXXX into a link that pulls up transaction info. I can't figure out how to create this in PHP with preg_replace, so it only formats the transaction ID into the link.

I have the link that is needed to lookup the transaction info, but I just do not know how to use regex to find the transaction ID and then wrap a link around it.
DATA;

$regex = '~\b[\dA-Z]{17}\b~';

$string_with_links = preg_replace($regex, "http://www.exaple.com/id/$0", $string);
echo $string_with_links;
?>
```

Comment: This does not work if a 17 letters word exists before transaction id, for example : https://regex101.com/r/kFB3zh/1

Comment: @stej4n: True. But without further specifications, it will be hard to write a regex alone (as already mentioned in my text above).

Comment: @Jan PayPal Transaction IDs are 17 characters combined of uppercase letters and numbers. Maybe you could update it so it only checks if all the letters are uppercase? That would prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the transaction ID, then you must simply use this link :

`https://www.paypal.com/__LANGUAGE__/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_view-a-trans&id=__TRANSACTION_ID__`

**where**

`__LANGUAGE__` is the language (2 letters, lowercase, for example *en, fr, it*...)

`__TRANSACTION_ID__` is the 17 characterss transaction id

**Sample link**

https://www.paypal.com/fr/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_view-a-trans&id=7FB54205R7031312B

**Edit**

Let's say you want to extract transaction id from this text :

> Hi there, my name is John Doe. I made a purchase and I'm having issues with it. Transaction ID: 7FB54205R7031312B.

Then you can use this regexp : `(?<=\s)([A-Z\d]{17})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IPblV7/1)

**Sample PHP code**

```
$string = "Hi there, my name is John Doe. I made a purchase and I'm having issues with it. Transaction ID: 7FB54205R7031312B.";
$pattern = '/(?<=\s)([A-Z\d]{17})/';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$transaction_ID = $matches[0];
$language = 'en';

$url = 'https://www.paypal.com/'.$language.'/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_view-a-trans&id='.$transaction_ID;
echo $url;
```

[Online demo](https://repl.it/HVpm/0)

**Note**

> Code will also work with text like *Hi I'm John Doe. transaction: 7FB54205R7031312B can you help me?*

Comment: When users post let us say. "Hi there, my name is John Doe. I made a purchase and I'm having issues with it. Transaction ID: XXXXXX". I need to be able to turn the XXXX into a link that pulls up transaction info. I can't figure out how to create this in PHP with preg_replace, so it only formats the transaction ID into the link.

Comment: I have the link that is needed to lookup the transaction info, but I just do not know how to use regex to find the transaction ID and then wrap a link around it.

Comment: What if they do not type "ID:" what if they just type the 17 chars?

Comment: Then simply match any 17 characters word preceded by a whitespece with only uppercase letters and numbers : `(?<=\s)([A-Z\d]{17})`